# I want to Create Xunit test for this controller. How can i do that

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, xunit, servicetestcase

I have created small kind of xunit test case but I don't know how to create this controller which i have mention below.

```
    public class PropertyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        private readonly ILogger<PropertyController> _logger;

        public PropertyController(IMediator mediator, ILogger<PropertyController> logger)
        {
            _mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddProperty([FromBody] AddPropertyCommand command)
        {
            bool commandResult = false;
            _logger.LogInformation(
                "----- Sending command: {CommandName} - {IdProperty}: {CommandId} ({@Command})",
                command.GetGenericTypeName(),
                nameof(command.ModifiedUserId),
                command.ModifiedUserId,
                command);
            commandResult = await _mediator.Send(command);
            if (!commandResult)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

## I have created like this. i have mock the dependency and create a test case for add command is working fine or not

```
public class PropertyControllerTest
    {
        private readonly PropertyController _it;
        private readonly Mock<IMediator> _mediatorMock;
        private readonly Mock<ILogger<PropertyController>> _loggerPropertycontrollerMock;

        public PropertyControllerTest()
        {
            _mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
            _loggerPropertycontrollerMock = new Mock<ILogger<PropertyController>>();
            _it = new PropertyController(_mediatorMock.Object, _loggerPropertycontrollerMock.Object);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void it_Should_add_information_successfully_and_returns_200_status_result()
        {
            //How can i write xunit test case. I'm creating like this
            _mediatorMock.Setup(x => x.Send().Returns(property);   
        }
```

Comment: what you want to test from this action method?

Comment: i want to test add method

Comment: Include your test case code as text rather than an image (just like you did with your PropertyController class)

Comment: i have added propertyControllerTests file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test below covers the 200 status result - a similar test for bad requests would be very similar.

```
[Fact]
public void it_Should_add_information_successfully_and_returns_200_status_result()
{
    // Arrange
    var expected = new AddPropertyCommand();
    _mediatorMock.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<AddPropertyCommand>())).Returns(true);

    // Act
    var actionResult = _it.AddProperty(expected);

    // Assert
    actionResult.ShouldBeAssignableTo<OkResult>();

    _mediatorMock.Verify(x => x.Send(expected));
}
```

N.B. `actionResult.ShouldBeAssignableTo<OkResult>();` is written using the Shouldly assertion framework, you can swap that out for anything you like. The one built into XUnit would be like this: `Assert.IsType(typeof(OkResult), actionResult);`

Comment: Many thanks but i am getting error
Error:- The name 'Arg' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry - `It.IsAny<AddPropertyCommand>()` I swap between Moq and NSubstitute and always get those things confused, I'll update my answer

Comment: Superb! Many Thanks. It is working fine. but i have question. here we have mock two dependencies so we have to SetUp other dependency as well in Testcase ?

Comment: When using Moq and mocked dependency method call will return null if there isn't a setup telling it to do otherwise. So you only have to setup the other mock calls if you a) you care about what it needs to do or b) not setting it up will stop you getting to the bit you want to  test. I'd recommend only setting up things that you need for that specific test otherwise your tests become harder to maintain and read. The less code there is in a test the better- generally!